# MySQL How to remove min and max and take average of remaining values from a row?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL DB (Version 5.5.31) say table1 with description:

```
mysql> desc table1;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| ts                 | timestamp    | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| type               | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| calculated_percent | int(3)       | NO   |     | 100                 |       |
| used               | int(11)      | NO   |     | 100                 |       |
| available          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 100                 |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

This table gets updated every five minutes with real time data. 
What I am trying to do is get average of calculated_percent, by checking ts. ts should be between "current time" and "current time - 1 hour". This same time slot will be checked for past 6 weeks for the same day of the week. 
I can get data until this point using following query:

```
mysql> SELECT 
-> type, 
-> sum1/count1 AS avg1, 
-> sum2/count2 AS avg2, 
-> sum3/count3 AS avg3, 
-> sum4/count4 AS avg4, 
-> sum5/count5 AS avg5, 
-> sum6/count6 AS avg6 
-> FROM ( 
-> SELECT 
-> type, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum1, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count1, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum2, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count2, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum3, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count3, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum4, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count4, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum5, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count5, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum6, 
-> SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count6 
-> FROM table1 
-> WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) 
-> GROUP BY type 
-> ) AS baseview; 
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+ 
| type | avg1 | avg2 | avg3 | avg4 | avg5 | avg6 | 
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+ 
| O | 24.5833 | 18.0286 | 17.9843 | 17.6145 | 17.8780 | 17.7976 | 
| R | 30.4167 | 23.0656 | 23.0620 | 22.5315 | 22.9573 | 22.7793 | 
| S | 5.5833 | 2.4963 | 2.4958 | 2.4665 | 2.4893 | 2.5833 | 
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+ 
3 rows in set (0.44 sec) 

mysql>
```

Now my question is, is there any way I can skip min and max values from the 6 weeks(avg1-avg6) and calculate average of remaining 4 weeks?

As these values are in row instead of column, I couldn't find a way to use MIN/MAX functions there. I am searching if creating temp table could help in any way here. 
I can also avoid using "GROUP BY type" and create 3 separate queries for each type (O, R and S) if that might be of any help.

Another option that could help me here is if I get values of avg1-avg6 in single column instead of 6 different columns. Is there any way (using UNION, etc) to get data in this format:

```
+-------------------+---------+
| type              | average |
+-------------------+---------+
| O                 | 24.5833 |
| O                 | 18.0286 |
| O                 | 17.9843 |
| O                 | 17.6145 |
| O                 | 17.8780 |
| O                 | 17.7976 |
| R                 | 30.4167 |
| R                 | 23.0656 |
| R                 | 23.0620 |
| R                 | 22.5315 |
| R                 | 22.9573 |
| R                 | 22.7793 |
| S                 |  5.5833 |
| S                 |  2.4963 |
| S                 |  2.4958 |
| S                 |  2.4665 |
| S                 |  2.4893 |
| S                 |  2.5833 |
+-------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I am using simple UNION. Though it's hard way and the query is quite large and ugly, it enables me to skip min and max values from the 6 weeks(avg1-avg6) and calculate average of remaining 4 weeks as I can get the 6 week values in same column instead of 6 different columns.

```
SELECT type, (SUM(Average) - (MIN(Average) + MAX(Average)))/4 as FourWeekAverage FROM
(
SELECT
  type,
  sum1/count1 AS Average
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum1,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count1
  FROM table1
  WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week)
  AND type = 'O'
) AS baseview
UNION
SELECT
  type,
  sum2/count2 AS Average
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 2 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum2,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 2 week), 1, 0)) as count2
  FROM table1
  WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week)
  AND type = 'O'
) AS baseview
UNION
SELECT
  type,
  sum3/count3 AS Average
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 3 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum3,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 3 week), 1, 0)) as count3
  FROM table1
  WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week)
  AND type = 'O'
) AS baseview
UNION
SELECT
  type,
  sum4/count4 AS Average
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 4 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum4,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 4 week), 1, 0)) as count4
  FROM table1
  WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week)
  AND type = 'O'
) AS baseview
UNION
SELECT
  type,
  sum5/count5 AS Average
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 5 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum5,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 5 week), 1, 0)) as count5
  FROM table1
  WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week)
  AND type = 'O'
) AS baseview
UNION
SELECT
  type,
  sum6/count6 AS Average
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 6 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum6,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 6 week), 1, 0)) as count6
  FROM table1
  WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week)
  AND type = 'O'
) AS baseview
) AS baseview;
```

Output is:

```
+---------+-----------------+
| type    | FourWeekAverage |
+---------+-----------------+
| O       |     37.43750000 |
+---------+-----------------+
```

There is still one problem left though which I found while testing. If there are two or more exact same values among the 6 weeks, I think the MIN/MAX functions don't work properly and the FourWeekAverage value is calculated wrong. I am still looking for a way to make query immune to this situation.

Comment: What should happen in the case you have 1 or more exact avg values in the 6 week sample?

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding here. I want only one of those values to be considered in MIN or MAX. Right now I am unable to figure out what is happening but it doesn't calculate the average correctly when I have more than 1 exact same avg values among the 6 week sample. The final goal is to have 4 values while taking final average from the 6.

Answer (score 0):

Given this result set:

```
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+ 
| type | avg1 | avg2 | avg3 | avg4 | avg5 | avg6 | 
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+ 
| O | 24.5833 | 18.0286 | 17.9843 | 17.6145 | 17.8780 | 17.7976 | 
| R | 30.4167 | 23.0656 | 23.0620 | 22.5315 | 22.9573 | 22.7793 | 
| S | 5.5833 | 2.4963 | 2.4958 | 2.4665 | 2.4893 | 2.5833 | 
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What if you remove 1 high value and 1 low value, subtract from total and average

```
(
  (avg1 + avg2 + avg3 + avg4 + avg5 + avg6) -
  (least(avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5, avg6) + greatest(avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5, avg6))
)
/ 4
```

E.G.

```
select (total - (min + max)) / 4 avg , total, min, max  from(
  select
  least(24.5833, 18.0286, 17.9843, 17.6145, 17.8780, 17.7976) min,
  greatest(24.5833, 18.0286, 17.9843, 17.6145, 17.8780, 17.7976) max,
  24.5833 + 18.0286 + 17.9843 + 17.6145 + 17.8780 + 17.7976 total
) q;

#17.92212500    113.8863    17.6145 24.5833
```